# Storing and Changing values in a DataGrid -- MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

In my program I have a `DataGrid` that is part of a UserControl. I would like to be able to change the values of the cells in this grid, and have them stored in a Data Model. This is similar to how a standard data bound `textBox` would work in wpf.

The `DataGrid` is composed of `TextBox`es. I am able to change the values in the cells, but they disappear after navigating away from the page.

UserControl XAML:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DataModel.Collection}" ... >
              <DataGrid.Columns>
                   <DataGridTemplateColumn IsReadOnly="True">
                         <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                               <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding rowNum}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                         </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                          .......
                    </DataGrid>
```

Data Model:

```
public class Data_Model : PropertyChangedBase
{
    private string one = "One";
    private string two = "Two";
    private string three = "Three";
    private string four = "Four";
    private string a = "A";
    private string b = "B";
    private string c = "C";
    private string d = "D";

    private ObservableCollection<Class> _Collection; 

    public Data_Model()
    {
        Collection = new ObservableCollection<Class>();
        Collection.Add(new Class() { rowNum = 0, input = one, output = a });
        Collection.Add(new Class() { rowNum = 1, input = two, output = b});
        Collection.Add(new Class() { rowNum = 2, input = three, output = c});
        Collection.Add(new Class() { rowNum = 3, input = four, output = d});

    }

    public ObservableCollection<Class> Collection {...}
}

public class Class //Class for DataGrid values
{
    public int rowNum { set; get; }
    public string input { set; get; }
    public string output { set; get; }
}
```

How can I store user entered values in these cells like one usually would (by writing a property for the `string` serving as the text in the `textBox`) ?

Comment: Your classes names confuse me. it seems like `DataClass` is your Model (or Data Model) and `Data_Model` is actually you viewModel ...

Comment: Why are you templating your columns as `TextBox`es? If this is for editing purposes `DataGrid` supports this out-of-the-box

Comment: I fixed the names. `Class` is just for the values stored in the `DataGrid`, and `Data_Model` is my Data Model. Also... if not `TextBox`, how exactly do I do an equivalent without a control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you just need to Call NotifyPropertyChanged("PropertyName") for each  property in your data_model and set the binding `Mode=twoway`

```
private int rowNum;

public int RowNum
{
    get { return rowNum; }
    set
    {
        rowNum = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("RowNum");
    }
}
```

Also, you can try DataGridTextColumn instead of templatecolumn as follow

```
<Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="customerdata" Source="customers.xml" XPath="Data" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource customerdata}, XPath=Customer}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding XPath=@FirstName}" FontFamily="Arial" FontStyle="Italic" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding XPath=@LastName}" FontFamily="Arial" FontWeight="Bold" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: The WPF TextBox binds two-ways by default.

Comment: It was the change to `DataGridTextColumn` that worked for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The WPF DataGrid uses transaction scope when cells are editable.  It means that the DataGrid is posting 'Commit' and 'Cancel' commands which your View Model isn't listening to at the moment.  That's why the changes do not appear to persist (i.e., you're ignoring the 'commits' on those instances).

In order to capture 'Commit' and 'Cancel' messages, the bound class should implement IEditableObject and code the necessary logic.  The docs on IEditableObject are here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ieditableobject.aspx

When a 'cancel' is done on a **ROW**, the grid does a roll-back on all the commits done on the **CELLS** of that row.  This aspect of the WPF DataGrid has foxed a lot of people, and so it's acquired the status of a 'gotcha'...

> If you are not familiar with IEditableObject, see this MSDN article
>   which has a good explanation and code sample.  The DataGrid has baked
>   in functionality for transactional editing via the IEditableObject
>   interface.  When you begin editing a cell, the DataGrid gets into cell
>   editing mode as well as row editing mode.  What this means is that you
>   can cancel/commit cells as well as cancel/commit rows.  For example, I
>   edit cell 0 and press tab to the next cell.  Cell 0 is committed when
>   pressing tab.  I start typing in cell 1 and realize I want to cancel
>   the operation.  I press ‘Esc’ which reverts cell 1.  I now realize I
>   want to cancel the whole operation so I press ‘Esc’ again and now cell
>   0 is reverted back to its original value.

Source:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vinsibal/archive/2009/04/07/5-random-gotchas-with-the-wpf-datagrid.aspx

So implement IEditableObject on the 'Class' class and you'll start to get the behaviour you are looking for.  This is what it should look like when you're done...

```
public class Class : INotifyPropertyChanged, IEditableObject
{
    private int _rowNum;
    public int RowNum
    {
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        get { return _rowNum; }
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        set
        {
            if (value != _rowNum)
            {
                _rowNum = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("RowNum");
            }
        }
    }
    private string _input;
    public string Input
    {
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        get { return _input; }
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        set
        {
            if (value != _input)
            {
                _input = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Input");
            }
        }
    }
    private string _output;
    public string Output
    {
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        get { return _output; }
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        set
        {
            if (value != _output)
            {
                _output = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Output");
            }
        }
    }
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        var handler = System.Threading.Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref PropertyChanged, null, null);
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
    #endregion
    #region IEditableObject Implementationi
    public void BeginEdit()
    {
        // your implementation goes here
    }
    public void CancelEdit()
    {
        // your implementation goes here
    }
    public void EndEdit()
    {
        // your implementation goes here
    }
    #endregion
}
```